# How to always lock Macbook when it's closed

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors, macbook, lock-screen

I use a second display at work but don't close the laptop. I want it to lock when it's closed regardless of what peripherals are plugged in. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: do you need it to be natively done in the operating system, or are you willing to use a 3rd party app

Comment: I'd prefer it to be done natively. I was hoping for some configuration, even if that happens to be a console command.